# what is the relationship betwen $L(s,sym^mf\times sym^mg)$ symmetric L function of $f$ and $g$ and $\lambda_{f}(n^m)$, $\lambda_{g}(n^m)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

what is the relationship betwen   $L(s,sym^mf\times sym^mg)$   symmetric  L function of $f$ and $g$ and   $\lambda_{f}(n^m)$, $\lambda_{g}(n^m)$ ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the L-function?